# Automatic update in product price on basis of quantity for ticketing website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I'm having a project where I need the price to be increased/decreased with an increase/decrease in the quantity. That quantity will be written in a simple HTML5 Form TextBox with an attribute of `type="number"`. All the styles and other PHP is already applied. But I don't know how to carry out this task with jQuery. Morever, I don't have any submit button. I need to multiply the original price with quantity instantly like any pro eCommerce website.

My code is below:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ticket-counter">
    <div class="header">Hey, Grab your ticket at this fabulous <?php
        if ($array['eventType'] == 'marriage') {
            echo 'Marriage';
        } else if ($array['eventType'] == 'baby-shower') {
            echo "Baby Shower";
        } else {
            echo "Session";
        }
        ?>!
    </div>
    <div class="contains">
        <div class="head">Ticket cost includes <input id="quantity" type="number" value="1" name="quantity" min="1"
                                                      max="6"/> persons.
        </div>
        <div class="facility">Meal
            <pre>X1</pre>
        </div>
        <div class="facility">All Taxes
            <pre>X1</pre>
        </div>
        <div class="facility">Whole Event
            <pre>X1</pre>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="conclude">
        <div class="head">So what? Grab the Event at just $<?php echo $array['eventFees']; ?></div>
        <div class="pay-btn">Pay $<?php echo $array['eventFees']; ?></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So here, I want `$array['eventFees']` to multiply with an increase in the field of quantity. You may see the field at this markup: `<input id="quantity" />` I also want an increase of number in the `<pre</pre>` tags.

Thanks in advance for the help. :-)

Comment: what have you tried? Have you had a look at the DOM events *oninput* and *onchange* ?

Comment: no, I'm unaware about javascripts. I program with advanced php, html and css. Sorry, I dont know the terms you spoke of.

Comment: well then learn js. This site is not an *please code that for me*. Its a help site for people trying to learn a language

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your JQuery script:

```
$("#quantity").bind('keyup mouseup', function () {
   var quantity = $(this.value);
   var youPrice(s) = $("#price(s)").value; //if your prices are in an array you will have to use a loop, 

  var total = quantity * youPrice(s);         
});

return total
```

Comment: can you also write the lines of code inside the function please

Comment: `bind` is deprecated in favor of `on`. Please use on

Comment: sorry, but nothing changed. should I make changes in my upper code too?